# Rounding down to one decimal place in SAS

Tags: sas

I want to round down both numbers and percentages to one decimal place.

For ex: 2.99, 2.92, 2.94, 2.987,2.901...all such values should be displayed as "2.9"

Similarly 1.24% , 1.26%, 1.298%, 1.223% should all be displayed as "1.2%".

Answer (score 3):

There isn't a round-down tool in SAS that's not for integers, but you can do it easily with the integer options and some math.

```
floor(numvar*10)/10
```

Percentages depend on how they're stored; if they are stored with PERCENT format, then they are really thousandths place, so replace 10 with 1000 above.